# Stripe charges retrieving shipping information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I'm trying to create an order through a stripe charge.  Currently, I can grab the billing address from a charge with **billing_address: charge.source.address_line1** but I cannot grab the shipping information.

**ChargesController**

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController

def create
 @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])

 #1 Create a charge
 customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
   email: current_user.email,
   card: params[:stripeToken]
 )

  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    customer: customer.id, # Note -- this is NOT the user_id in your app
    amount: (@product.price * 100).to_i,
    description: @product.title,
    currency: 'usd',
  )

 #3 Create an Order
 Order.create(
   user: current_user,
   billing_address: charge.source.address_line1
  )


  flash[:notice] = "Thank you for your order, #{current_user.email}! "
  redirect_to books_path # or wherever

 rescue Stripe::CardError => e
  flash[:error] = e.message
  redirect_to new_charge_path
 end
end
```

**The form**

```
<%= form_tag charges_path do %>
 <h4>Click the button!</h4>
 <script 
  class='stripe-button' 
  src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" 
  data-key="<%= @stripe_btn_data[:key] %>" 
  data-amount=<%= @stripe_btn_data[:amount] %> 
  data-description="<%= @stripe_btn_data[:description] %>" 
  data-shipping-address="<%= @stripe_btn_data[:shipping] %>"
  data-billing-address="<%= @stripe_btn_data[:billing] %>"
></script>
<%= hidden_field_tag :product_id, @product.id %>
```

**PostsController**

```
def show
 @stripe_btn_data = {
  key: "#{ Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] }",
  description: @product.title,
  amount: (@product.price * 100),
  shipping: :true,
  billing: :true     
}
```

How do I grab the shipping information from the stripe charge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error, I figured out how to insert the Stripe charge into my db with... **shipping_address: params[:stripeShippingAddressLine1]**

```
Order.create(
  user: current_user,
  billing_address: charge.source.address_line1,
  billing_city: charge.source.address_city,
  billing_state: charge.source.address_state,
  billing_zip: charge.source.address_zip,
  shipping_address: params[:stripeShippingAddressLine1]

  )
```